# Selecting second jQuery match when using click()

Tags: jquery, node.js, puppeteer

I'm experimenting with web scraping, but I've run into this minor issue. The website I want to scrape has 2 buttons, both with the same class. Using Puppeteer, I want to click the second button. Issue is, that I can't figure out how to select the second element when I have to do a string jQuery in the click function.

```
page.click('.ws-collapsable-block__heading')
```

The line above works great for clicking the first button, but as I said, I'm trying to click the second button. I've tried:

```
page.click('.ws-collapsable-block__heading:eq(1)')
page.click('.ws-collapsable-block__heading').eq(1)
page.click('.ws-collapsable-block__heading'.eq(1))
page.click('.ws-collapsable-block__heading'[1])
page.click('.ws-collapsable-block__heading')[1]
```

None of them work though.

My second solution was using a traditional jQuery DOM search like this:

```
document.querySelector('.ws-collapsable-block__heading')
```

but I can't access "document" outside a page evaluation, and I can't access page inside an evaluation.

Full script underneath:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function get_info(code) {

    let url = 'https://joker.no/sok?query=' + code

    let browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    let page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })

    let get_link = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.ws-product__title').getAttribute('href') )
    let product_name = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.ws-product__title').innerText );

    await page.goto('https://joker.no' + get_link)

    // This clicks the first button...
    page.click('.ws-collapsable-block__heading')

    await page.screenshot({path: 'x.png'})    
}

get_info('7311041013663')
```

Edit: I tried using nth like this

```
page.click('.ws-collapsable-block__heading:nth-child(2)')
```

but it gives this error

```
(node:5856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: .ws-collapsable-block__heading:nth-child(2)
    at assert (E:\Node\KaloriApp\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:283:11)
    at DOMWorld.click (E:\Node\KaloriApp\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\DOMWorld.js:366:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (E:\Node\KaloriApp\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.click (E:\Node\KaloriApp\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:1067:29)
    at get_info (E:\Node\KaloriApp\app.js:17:10)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:5856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5856) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

If I try document.querySelectorAll('.ws-collapsable-block__heading:nth-child(1)') on the website, I get a nodeList with size 3. I still have to do document.querySelectorAll('.ws-collapsable-block__heading:nth-child(1)')[1] to get the second element though, which I can't seem to do in the click function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily grab all the products with the `page.$$` method and then click one of them. Don't forget to add `await`.

For instance:

```
const [ firstProduct, secondProduct, thirdProduct ] = await page.$$('.ws-panel');

await secondProduct.click(); // click the second button
```

Comment: I completely overlooked the $$ function.

Answer (score 1):

Use nth-child selector

```
page.click('.ws-collapsable-block__heading:nth-child(2)')
```

Comment: This gives an error which I've posted at the bottom of the original question.